# Can't get a For Each loop to contain multiple If functions

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a long code for 36 sheets in a workbook. My goal is to have specific cells be filled in prior to the user performing "Save As". My code works well for the first sheet as I wrote each required box individually in the code. But the other 35 sheets are all the same (it's for a device being tested by field technicians. Each sheet is for a single device and each customer has a different quantity of devices). With writing each box individually across those 35 sheets the code becomes to large.

So I'm attempting a For Each worksheet loop and writing the code only once, but it doesn't seem to work this way. I'm sure I've missed something in my code, but I've been staring at it too long to figure out. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Below is part of my code:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet


For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
  If ws.Name Like "*BF*" Then
   If Cells(17, 5) = "Reduced Pressure" And Cells(29, 5) = "" Then
      MsgBox "CHECK #1 missing value on Worksheets.Name", vbExclamation, "Dignity Fire Protection"
      Cancel = True
      Application.Goto Cells(29, 5)
    End If
     
   If Cells(17, 5) = "Reduced Pressure" And Cells(31, 5) = "" Then
      MsgBox "CHECK #2 missing value Worksheets.Name", vbExclamation, "Dignity Fire Protection"
      Cancel = True
      Application.Goto Cells(31, 5)
     End If
     
    If Cells(17, 5) = "Reduced Pressure" And Cells(33, 5) = "" Then
      MsgBox "RELIEF VALVE missing value Worksheets.Name", vbExclamation, "Dignity Fire Protection"
      Cancel = True
      Application.Goto Cells(33, 5)
     End If
     
    If Cells(17, 5) = "Double Check" And Cells(29, 5) = "" Then
      MsgBox "CHECK #1 missing value Worksheets.Name", vbExclamation, "Dignity Fire Protection"
      Cancel = True
      Application.Goto Cells(29, 5)
     End If
     
    If Cells(17, 5) = "Double Check" And Cells(31, 5) = "" Then
      MsgBox "CHECK #2 missing value Worksheets.Name", vbExclamation, "Dignity Fire Protection"
      Cancel = True
      Application.Goto Cells(31, 5)
     End If
     
    If Cells(17, 5) = "Pressure Vacuum Breaker" And Cells(29, 5) = "" Then
      MsgBox "CHECK #1 missing value on Worksheets.Name", vbExclamation, "Dignity Fire Protection"
      Cancel = True
      Application.Goto Cells(29, 5)
     End If
     
    If Cells(17, 5) = "Pressure Vacuum Breaker" And Cells(37, 5) = "" Then
      MsgBox "AIR INLET missing value on Worksheets.Name", vbExclamation, "Dignity Fire Protection"
      Cancel = True
      Application.Goto Cells(37, 5)
     End If
     
    If Cells(17, 5).Value > "" And Cells(39, 6) = "" Then
      MsgBox "SHUT OFF VAVLE #1 missing info on Worksheets.Name", vbExclamation, "Dignity Fire Protection"
      Cancel = True
      Application.Goto Cells(39, 6)
     End If
     
    If Cells(17, 5).Value > "" And Cells(39, 14) = "" Then
      MsgBox "SHUT OFF VAVLE #2 missing info on Worksheets.Name", vbExclamation, "Dignity Fire Protection"
      Cancel = True
      Application.Goto Cells(39, 14)
     End If
     
    If Cells(29, 5).Value > "" And Cells(19, 5) = "" Then
      MsgBox "ASSEMBLY TEST FOR missing info on Worksheets.Name", vbExclamation, "Dignity Fire Protection"
      Cancel = True
      Application.Goto Cells(19, 5)
     End If
     
    If Cells(29, 5).Value > "" And Cells(21, 5) = "" Then
      MsgBox "MANUFACTURER missing info on Worksheets.Name", vbExclamation, "Dignity Fire Protection"
      Cancel = True
      Application.Goto Cells(21, 5)
     End If
     
    If Cells(29, 5).Value > "" And Cells(22, 5) = "" Then
      MsgBox "SIZE FOR missing info on Worksheets.Name", vbExclamation, "Dignity Fire Protection"
      Cancel = True
      Application.Goto Cells(22, 5)
     End If
     
    If Cells(29, 5).Value > "" And Cells(23, 5) = "" Then
      MsgBox "LOCATION missing info on Worksheets.Name", vbExclamation, "Dignity Fire Protection"
      Cancel = True
      Application.Goto Cells(23, 5)
     End If
     
    If Cells(29, 5).Value > "" And Cells(17, 12) = "" Then
      MsgBox "ASSEMBLY FOR missing info on Worksheets.Name", vbExclamation, "Dignity Fire Protection"
      Cancel = True
      Application.Goto Cells(17, 12)
     End If
     
    If Cells(29, 5).Value > "" And Cells(19, 12) = "" Then
      MsgBox "ASSEMBLY USE missing info on Worksheets.Name", vbExclamation, "Dignity Fire Protection"
      Cancel = True
      Application.Goto Cells(19, 12)
     End If
      
        If Cells(29, 5).Value > "" And Cells(21, 12) = "" Then
          MsgBox "MODEL NUMBER missing info on Worksheets.Name", vbExclamation, "Dignity Fire Protection"
         Cancel = True
         Application.Goto Cells(21, 12)
         End If
     
       If Cells(29, 5).Value > "" And Cells(22, 12) = "" Then
         MsgBox "SERIAL NUMBER missing info on Worksheets.Name", vbExclamation, "Dignity Fire Protection"
          Cancel = True
          Application.Goto Cells(22, 12)
        End If
     
        If Cells(29, 5).Value > "" And Cells(23, 12) = "" Then
         MsgBox "LINE PRESSURE missing info on Worksheets.Name", vbExclamation, "Dignity Fire Protection"
         Cancel = True
          Application.Goto Cells(23, 12)
         End If
     
        If Cells(29, 5).Value > "" And Cells(45, 11) = "" Then
         MsgBox "QUESTION #1 missing on Worksheets.Name", vbExclamation, "Dignity Fire Protection"
         Cancel = True
         Application.Goto Cells(45, 11)
         End If
      
        If Cells(29, 5).Value > "" And Cells(46, 11) = "" Then
          MsgBox "QUESTION #2 missing on Worksheets.Name", vbExclamation, "Dignity Fire Protection"
          Cancel = True
          Application.Goto Cells(46, 11)
         End If
      
        If Cells(29, 5).Value > "" And Cells(47, 11) = "" Then
         MsgBox "QUESTION #3 missing on Worksheets.Name", vbExclamation, "Dignity Fire Protection"
         Cancel = True
         Application.Goto Cells(47, 11)
         End If
      
        If Cells(29, 5).Value > "" And Cells(48, 11) = "" Then
          MsgBox "QUESTION #4 missing on Worksheets.Name", vbExclamation, "Dignity Fire Protection"
          Cancel = True
          Application.Goto Cells(48, 11)
         End If
      
        If Cells(29, 5).Value > "" And Cells(49, 11) = "" Then
          MsgBox "QUESTION #5 missing on Worksheets.Name", vbExclamation, "Dignity Fire Protection"
          Cancel = True
          Application.Goto Cells(49, 11)
         End If
    
        If Cells(29, 5).Value > "" And Cells(50, 11) = "" Then
          MsgBox "BACKFLOW PASS/FAIL missing on Worksheets.Name", vbExclamation, "Dignity Fire Protection"
          Cancel = True
          Application.Goto Cells(50, 11)
         End If
Next ws

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `Next` should be after all the `If`s you want in the loop. edit: I see you edited your question to remove it, where is it in your code?

Comment: Maybe try : `If ws.Name Like "BF" Then` ... `If Cells(17, 5) = "Reduced Pressure" And Cells(29, 5) = "" Then` ...... `elseif Cells(17, 5) = "Reduced Pressure" And Cells(31, 5) = "" Then` .... `end if` ... `end if` .... 'next`

Comment: I tried your code. i added the missing code  : end if, next and end sub at the end of the code.  I also edited the  like "BF" to like "\*BF\*".  it seems working fine..

Comment: It is at the very end. I will post all my code in this reply for you to see the entire For Each process I want performed;

Comment: Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name Like "BF" Then
       If Cells(17, 5) = "Reduced Pressure" And Cells(29, 5) = "" Then
          MsgBox "CHECK #1 missing value on Worksheets.Name", vbExclamation, 
          Cancel = True
          Application.Goto Cells(29, 5)
        End If
        
        If Cells(29, 5).Value > "" And Cells(50, 11) = "" Then
          MsgBox "BACKFLOW PASS/FAIL missing on Worksheets.Name", 
          Cancel = True
          Application.Goto Cells(50, 11)
         End If
Next ws

End If

End Sub

Comment: The code does seem to compile just fine in VBA but when I try to Save As it saves anyways and doesn't pop up the message box I want it to or goto the affected cell as the Application GoTo is expecting.

Comment: If I do an Else If will it still run the 1st if and then the 2nd if and so on. I have 26 total if statements within the For Each Loop

Comment: Consider [editing you question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75868881/edit) instead of adding hard to parse code in comments

Comment: I have now updated the question to show the entire code I am trying to write

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name Like "BF" Then
        If ws.Cells(17, 5) = "Reduced Pressure" Then
            If ws.Cells(29, 5) = "" Then
                MsgBox "CHECK #1 missing value on Worksheets.Name", vbExclamation, "Dignity Fire Protection"
                Cancel = True
            ElseIf ws.Cells(31, 5) = "" Then
                 MsgBox "CHECK #2 missing value Worksheets.Name", vbExclamation, "Dignity Fire Protection"
                 Cancel = True
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next ws
```

Comment: If I try this, will it run both if's or just one or the other?

Comment: Don't the `Cells()` need a `ws.` adding ? Also maybe message should be `"CHECK #1 missing value on " & ws.Name`

Comment: @CDP1802 good point, edited the code in consequence. It's what come of just copy/^pasting code without looking at it too closely...

Comment: @Chassee Try stepping through the code

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "Try stepping through the code"

Comment: I didn't want to put the ws. before Cells() as I want it to run on just the sheet it is looking at through the entire 26 functions then move to the next sheet and do the same on only that sheet

Comment: 1. to step through code, press f8 in the VBA editor (if you don't want to step through my code, try running it on a copy of the workbook). 2. the sheet referred to by `ws` will change as you loop through the sheets, if you don't specify a sheet, the active sheet will be used by default

Comment: Yes I want to use only the active sheet. I have updated my entire code into the question now. I will try f8 and see what that does

Comment: I have tried on a copy of the workbook. I am attempting to save as with info not fully filled in. The error I receive is "Next without For"

Answer (score 0):

I answered my question with the help of all of you above. Thank you for all the comments and suggestions. Here is the code for all to see. Thanks again. YOU ARE ALL AMAZING!!!!!

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

If Worksheets("Service Receipt").Cells(9, 2) > "" And Worksheets("Service Receipt").Cells(10, 2) = "" Then
MsgBox "ADDRESS Missing on Service Receipt", vbInformation, "Dignity Fire Protection"
Cancel = True
Application.Goto Worksheets("Service Receipt").Cells(10, 2)
End If

If Worksheets("Service Receipt").Cells(9, 2) > "" And Worksheets("Service Receipt").Cells(11, 2) = "" Then
MsgBox "CITY Missing on Service Receipt", vbInformation, "Dignity Fire Protection"
Cancel = True
Application.Goto Worksheets("Service Receipt").Cells(11, 2)
End If

If Worksheets("Service Receipt").Cells(9, 2) > "" And Worksheets("Service Receipt").Cells(11, 5) = "" Then
MsgBox "ZIP CODE Missing on Service Receipt", vbInformation, "Dignity Fire Protection"
Cancel = True
Application.Goto Worksheets("Service Receipt").Cells(11, 5)
End If

If Worksheets("Service Receipt").Cells(9, 2) > "" And Worksheets("Service Receipt").Cells(5, 9) = "" Then
MsgBox "DATE Missing on Service Receipt", vbInformation, "Dignity Fire Protection"
Cancel = True
Application.Goto Worksheets("Service Receipt").Cells(5, 9)
End If

If Worksheets("Service Receipt").Cells(9, 2) > "" And Worksheets("Service Receipt").Cells(9, 9) = "" Then
MsgBox "JOB NUMBER Missing on Service Receipt", vbInformation, "Dignity Fire Protection"
Cancel = True
Application.Goto Worksheets("Service Receipt").Cells(9, 9)
End If

If Worksheets("Service Receipt").Cells(9, 2) > "" And Worksheets("Service Receipt").Cells(10, 9) = "" Then
MsgBox "YOUR NAME(INSPECTED BY) Missing on Service Receipt", vbInformation, "Dignity Fire Protection"
Cancel = True
Application.Goto Worksheets("Service Receipt").Cells(10, 9)
End If

If Worksheets("Service Receipt").Cells(9, 2) > "" And Worksheets("Service Receipt").Cells(11, 13) = "" Then
MsgBox "YOUR CERT NUMBER Missing on Service Receipt", vbInformation, "Dignity Fire Protection"
Cancel = True
Application.Goto Worksheets("Service Receipt").Cells(11, 13)
End If

If Worksheets("Service Receipt").Cells(9, 2) > "" And Worksheets("Service Receipt").Cells(11, 9) = "" Then
MsgBox "TEST TYPE Missing on Service Receipt", vbInformation, "Dignity Fire Protection"
Cancel = True
Application.Goto Worksheets("Service Receipt").Cells(11, 9)
End If

If Worksheets("Service Receipt").Cells(9, 2) > "" And Worksheets("Service Receipt").Cells(12, 9) = "" Then
MsgBox "CERTIFICATION EXPIRATION Missing on Service Receipt", vbInformation, "Dignity Fire Protection"
Cancel = True
Application.Goto Worksheets("Service Receipt").Cells(12, 9)
End If

If Worksheets("Service Receipt").Cells(9, 2) > "" And Worksheets("Service Receipt").Cells(12, 12) = "" Then
MsgBox "GAUGE SERIAL NUMBER Missing on Service Receipt", vbInformation, "Dignity Fire Protection"
Cancel = True
Application.Goto Worksheets("Service Receipt").Cells(12, 12)
End If

If Worksheets("Service Receipt").Cells(9, 2) > "" And Worksheets("Service Receipt").Cells(13, 11) = "" Then
MsgBox "GAUGE RECALIBRATION DATE Missing on Service Receipt", vbInformation, "Dignity Fire Protection"
Cancel = True
Application.Goto Worksheets("Service Receipt").Cells(13, 11)
End If

If Worksheets("Service Receipt").Cells(9, 2) > "" And Worksheets("Service Receipt").Cells(16, 1) = "" Then
MsgBox "SERVICE CALL QUANTITY Missing on Service Receipt", vbInformation, "Dignity Fire Protection"
Cancel = True
Application.Goto Worksheets("Service Receipt").Cells(16, 1)
End If

If Worksheets("Service Receipt").Cells(9, 2) > "" And Worksheets("Service Receipt").Cells(16, 11) = "" Then
MsgBox "SERVICE CALL $ AMOUNT Missing on Service Receipt", vbInformation, "Dignity Fire Protection"
Cancel = True
Application.Goto Worksheets("Service Receipt").Cells(16, 11)
End If

If Worksheets("Service Receipt").Cells(17, 1) > "0" And Worksheets("Service Receipt").Cells(17, 11) = "" Then
MsgBox "BACKFLOW $ AMOUNT Missing on Service Receipt", vbInformation, "Dignity Fire Protection"
Cancel = True
Application.Goto Worksheets("Service Receipt").Cells(17, 11)
End If

 If Worksheets("Service Receipt").Cells(9, 2) > "" And Worksheets("Service Receipt").Cells(53, 1) = "" Then
 MsgBox "NOTES TO OFFICE Missing on Service Receipt", vbInformation, "Dignity Fire Protection"
 Cancel = True
 Application.Goto Worksheets("Service Receipt").Cells(53, 1)
 End If


Dim ws As Worksheet


For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
  If ws.Name Like "*BF*" Then

   If ws.Cells(17, 5) = "Reduced Pressure" And ws.Cells(29, 5) = "" Then
      MsgBox "CHECK #1 missing value on ws.Name", vbExclamation, "Dignity Fire Protection"
      Cancel = True
      Application.Goto ws.Cells(29, 5)
    End If
     
   If ws.Cells(17, 5) = "Reduced Pressure" And ws.Cells(31, 5) = "" Then
      MsgBox "CHECK #2 missing value ws.Name", vbExclamation, "Dignity Fire Protection"
      Cancel = True
      Application.Goto ws.Cells(31, 5)
     End If
     
    If ws.Cells(17, 5) = "Reduced Pressure" And ws.Cells(33, 5) = "" Then
      MsgBox "RELIEF VALVE missing value ws.Name", vbExclamation, "Dignity Fire Protection"
      Cancel = True
      Application.Goto ws.Cells(33, 5)
     End If
     
    If ws.Cells(17, 5) = "Double Check" And ws.Cells(29, 5) = "" Then
      MsgBox "CHECK #1 missing value ws.Name", vbExclamation, "Dignity Fire Protection"
      Cancel = True
      Application.Goto ws.Cells(29, 5)
     End If
     
    If ws.Cells(17, 5) = "Double Check" And ws.Cells(31, 5) = "" Then
      MsgBox "CHECK #2 missing value ws.Name", vbExclamation, "Dignity Fire Protection"
      Cancel = True
      Application.Goto ws.Cells(31, 5)
     End If
     
    If ws.Cells(17, 5) = "Pressure Vacuum Breaker" And ws.Cells(29, 5) = "" Then
      MsgBox "CHECK #1 missing value on ws.Name", vbExclamation, "Dignity Fire Protection"
      Cancel = True
      Application.Goto ws.Cells(29, 5)
     End If
     
    If ws.Cells(17, 5) = "Pressure Vacuum Breaker" And ws.Cells(37, 5) = "" Then
      MsgBox "AIR INLET missing value on ws.Name", vbExclamation, "Dignity Fire Protection"
      Cancel = True
      Application.Goto ws.Cells(37, 5)
     End If
     
    If ws.Cells(17, 5).Value > "" And ws.Cells(39, 6) = "" Then
      MsgBox "SHUT OFF VAVLE #1 missing info on ws.Name", vbExclamation, "Dignity Fire Protection"
      Cancel = True
      Application.Goto ws.Cells(39, 6)
     End If
     
    If ws.Cells(17, 5).Value > "" And ws.Cells(39, 14) = "" Then
      MsgBox "SHUT OFF VAVLE #2 missing info on ws.Name", vbExclamation, "Dignity Fire Protection"
      Cancel = True
      Application.Goto ws.Cells(39, 14)
     End If
     
    If ws.Cells(29, 5).Value > "" And ws.Cells(19, 5) = "" Then
      MsgBox "ASSEMBLY TEST FOR missing info on ws.Name", vbExclamation, "Dignity Fire Protection"
      Cancel = True
      Application.Goto ws.Cells(19, 5)
     End If
     
    If ws.Cells(29, 5).Value > "" And ws.Cells(21, 5) = "" Then
      MsgBox "MANUFACTURER missing info on ws.Name", vbExclamation, "Dignity Fire Protection"
      Cancel = True
      Application.Goto ws.Cells(21, 5)
     End If
     
    If ws.Cells(29, 5).Value > "" And ws.Cells(22, 5) = "" Then
      MsgBox "SIZE FOR missing info on ws.Name", vbExclamation, "Dignity Fire Protection"
      Cancel = True
      Application.Goto ws.Cells(22, 5)
     End If
     
    If ws.Cells(29, 5).Value > "" And ws.Cells(23, 5) = "" Then
      MsgBox "LOCATION missing info on ws.Name", vbExclamation, "Dignity Fire Protection"
      Cancel = True
      Application.Goto ws.Cells(23, 5)
     End If
     
    If ws.Cells(29, 5).Value > "" And ws.Cells(17, 12) = "" Then
      MsgBox "ASSEMBLY FOR missing info on ws.Name", vbExclamation, "Dignity Fire Protection"
      Cancel = True
      Application.Goto ws.Cells(17, 12)
     End If
     
    If ws.Cells(29, 5).Value > "" And ws.Cells(19, 12) = "" Then
      MsgBox "ASSEMBLY USE missing info on ws.Name", vbExclamation, "Dignity Fire Protection"
      Cancel = True
      Application.Goto ws.Cells(19, 12)
     End If
     
    If ws.Cells(29, 5).Value > "" And ws.Cells(21, 12) = "" Then
      MsgBox "MODEL NUMBER missing info on ws.Name", vbExclamation, "Dignity Fire Protection"
      Cancel = True
      Application.Goto ws.Cells(21, 12)
     End If
     
    If ws.Cells(29, 5).Value > "" And ws.Cells(22, 12) = "" Then
      MsgBox "SERIAL NUMBER missing info on ws.Name", vbExclamation, "Dignity Fire Protection"
      Cancel = True
      Application.Goto ws.Cells(22, 12)
     End If
     
    If ws.Cells(29, 5).Value > "" And ws.Cells(23, 12) = "" Then
      MsgBox "LINE PRESSURE missing info on ws.Name", vbExclamation, "Dignity Fire Protection"
      Cancel = True
      Application.Goto ws.Cells(23, 12)
     End If
     
    If ws.Cells(29, 5).Value > "" And ws.Cells(45, 11) = "" Then
      MsgBox "QUESTION #1 missing on ws.Name", vbExclamation, "Dignity Fire Protection"
      Cancel = True
      Application.Goto ws.Cells(45, 11)
     End If
      
    If ws.Cells(29, 5).Value > "" And ws.Cells(46, 11) = "" Then
      MsgBox "QUESTION #2 missing on ws.Name", vbExclamation, "Dignity Fire Protection"
      Cancel = True
      Application.Goto ws.Cells(46, 11)
     End If
      
    If ws.Cells(29, 5).Value > "" And ws.Cells(47, 11) = "" Then
      MsgBox "QUESTION #3 missing on ws.Name", vbExclamation, "Dignity Fire Protection"
      Cancel = True
      Application.Goto ws.Cells(47, 11)
     End If
      
    If ws.Cells(29, 5).Value > "" And ws.Cells(48, 11) = "" Then
      MsgBox "QUESTION #4 missing on ws.Name", vbExclamation, "Dignity Fire Protection"
      Cancel = True
      Application.Goto ws.Cells(48, 11)
     End If
      
    If ws.Cells(29, 5).Value > "" And ws.Cells(49, 11) = "" Then
      MsgBox "QUESTION #5 missing on ws.Name", vbExclamation, "Dignity Fire Protection"
      Cancel = True
      Application.Goto ws.Cells(49, 11)
     End If
    
    If ws.Cells(29, 5).Value > "" And ws.Cells(50, 11) = "" Then
      MsgBox "BACKFLOW PASS/FAIL missing on ws.Name", vbExclamation, "Dignity Fire Protection"
      Cancel = True
      Application.Goto ws.Cells(50, 11)
     End If
End If
     
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: typos `SHUT OFF VAVLE #1` and `SHUT OFF VAVLE #2`. Also move the ws,name outside the quotes  eg. `"SHUT OFF VALVE #1 missing info on " &  ws.Name`. Same for all the other msgboxes.